# when python loads json,how to convert str to unicode ,so I can print Chinese characters?

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding

I got a json file like this:

```
{
    'errNum': 0,    
    'retData': {
    'city': "武汉"
    }
}

import json 
content = json.loads(result) # supposing json file named result
cityname = content['retData']['city'] 
print cityname
```

After that, I got  a output :  `\u6b66\u6c49` 
I know it's unicode of Chinese character of `武汉` ,but the type of it is str
`isinstance(cityname,str)` is True.
so  how can I convert this str to unicode and output will be `武汉`

I also have tried these solutions:

```
>>> u'\u6b66\u6c49'
u'\u6b66\u6c49'
>>> print u'\u6b66\u6c49'
武汉
>>> print '\u6b66\u6c49'.decode()
\u6b66\u6c49
>>> print '\u6b66\u6c49'
\u6b66\u6c49
```

Searched something about ascii,unicode and utf-8 ,encode and decode ,but also cannot understand,it is crazy!
I need some help ,Thanks !

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I‘m not quit sure about it ,all my code is placed in SinaAppEngine,a frameword named wsgi, I guess maybe it is Linux

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue; are you sure you used `print`? What does `print repr(cityname)` produce? What of `print repr(content)`?

Comment: Sorry, I comment    json.loads(result)  this line,it dosen't so  the content I got is not what parsed by json. So the problem I encountered is how to convert a str, whose value is unicode code of two Chinese characters ,to unicode. Maybe I don't describe it clearly. Simply, I got  a string '\u6b66\u6c49', how to convert it to  武汉, I dont know how it  works in json module ,thanks

Comment: @AdrianLeo: the `json` module takes care of such details *for* you, normally. Which is why I want to know the details of what *exactly* you are dealing with here, which is what the output of `repr()` would give me.

Comment: In python 2.7 the `\u` escape has no meaning in string literals, only in unicode literals (`u"abc"`). `print '\u6b66\u6c49'` will print the output shown in the OP. It appears the string returned by the JSON parser indeed starts with the characters '\', 'u', '6', 'b', …

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this answer comes five years too late, but since I had a similar issue that I was trying to solve, while building a preprocessor for the Japanese language, here is the answer I found.

when you `loads` the `result` to `content` add the following flag:

```
content = json.loads(result, ensure_ascii=False)
```

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score -2):

Your json contains escaped unicode characters. You can decode them into actual unicode characters using the `unicode_escape` codec:

```
print cityname.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Note that, while this will usually work, depending on the source of the unicode escaping you could have problems with characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0 to U+FFFF). A convenient quote from user @bobince that I took from a comment:

> Note that ... there are a number of different formats that use \u
>   escapes - Python unicode literals (which unicode-escape handles), Java
>   properties, JavaScript string literals, JSON, and so on. It is
>   important to know which one you are dealing with because they all have
>   slightly different rules about what other escapes are valid.
>   unicode-escape may or may not be a valid way of parsing that data
>   depending on where it comes from.

Comment: This would also 'decode' any other accidental escape sequences that start with ``\``, not just `\u....`. We are missing a piece of the puzzle here.